# Exception in creating Pivot Table due to Excel Version Upgrade

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have developed an application in vb.net which creates a excel pivot table in the report

The excel version on my machine got upgraded to 2010 from 2003 and the pivot table functionality is failing

I looked at the calls for both 2003 and 2010 versions and did not find any difference except 2003 has `WkbResult.PivotCaches.Add` and 2012 has `WkbResult.PivotCaches.Create`

```
Dim WksPivot As Excel.Worksheet = WkbResult.Worksheets("Summary")
Dim WksResult As Excel.Worksheet = WkbResult.Worksheets("Test_Details")
Dim PC As Excel.PivotCache = Nothing
Dim PTS As Excel.PivotTables = Nothing
Dim PT As Excel.PivotTable = Nothing

' This is where it fails even after i changed Add to Create method

PC = WkbResult.PivotCaches.Create(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, WksResult.Range("A:D"))
```

I tried to look at the references and have have changed the reference to a later version which shows on my machine but i am still getting the same exception

Here is the some part of the exception

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCaches.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType SourceType, Object SourceData, Object Version)
       at QCLite.PivotTableManager.CreateResultsPivotTable(Workbook& WkbResult, ListView lstResults) in C:\userdata\Framework\src\06 Utilities\QCLite\QCLite\PivotTableManager.vb:line 23
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for Excel 2010 the specification of range as ("A:D") does not work

I changed the call to

```
Dim TotalRows As Integer = WksResult.UsedRange.Rows.Count

PC = WkbResult.PivotCaches.Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, WksResult.Range("A1:D" & TotalRows))
```

and it worked like charm.

The Add call also worked fine surprisingly.